# Getting a error in google drive api integration & Permission with iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

I am developing a file manager kind of appellation. in this i have integrate Cloud like Dropbox, Box, Sky-drive and Google drive.

Now, everything is working fine but in Google Drive getting some issue like when i am creating a folder/file outside the app so folder/file displaying within app.

But when delete that folder/file outside the app its fine but still displaying within app after deleting it form outside the app. When i am logged out and logged in still folder/file is there.

If you have any suggestion for permission or integration google drive api than help me in this.

Thanks

Comment: perhaps it's only trashed. If so you need to exclude trashed files/folders in your queries

Comment: Thanks for reply #Pinoyyid but issue is like within a app google drive is not refreshing.. means any kind of action perform out side the app in side app is not working only delete functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can forgot in query `trashed=false.`
place try this in your query

`query.q = @"mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false";`

OR

just update your query

put in your query.

`trashed=false;`

I think It will work.in my site working find.